# Dividing a date value in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, database-migration

I am working on migrating an Access program into SQL Server.
The following is my SQL code taken directly from access.

```
(([Promise Date])-([Date Recieved]))/100
```

As you can see, I am attempting to do a division on a datetime value.

This is the error message i receive:

```
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the 
CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Both fields are type Datetime. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: The error message is clear: Convert the date values to Double/Float, and then perform the arithmetic.

Comment: What you are missing is that this is syntactic nonsense and that you have more work to be done - and perhaps additional learning to do before that. You will need to figure out what the result of that calculation should be and then translate that to tsql. I can guess that you should use datediff to get the number of days(?) between the dates and then divide, but I have no idea what it really does.

Comment: Applying arithmetic directly to dates, in truth, makes little sense. Dates aren't numbers, they're(unsurprisingly) dates. If i was to ask you what today (20190121) / 7 was, could you answer? What about (the date) 20170804 * 2? Without knowing what you are really trying to achieve here, the answer is difficult. I suspect the others are right, that you want the difference in days / 100, and thus you need to use `DATEDIFF`, however, we also then need to know some sample data and expected results.

Comment: If you have time values as well, this is really important, as something like `DATEDIFF(DAY,'2019-01-20T00:00:00', '2019-01-21T23:59:59')` is 1, despite basically being 2 days apart, where as `DATEDIFF(DAY,'2019-01-21T23:59:59','2019-01-22T00:00:01'`) is 1, despite there only be 2 seconds between the two date and times.

Comment: @larnu - the Access dates are IEEE doubles, with zero being 1899-12-31 I believe.  In the answer accepted I find that even SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2019-01-01', '2019-04-09')/100; returns zero, since DATEDIIF returns int and integer division takes over

Comment: Note that [`DateDiff`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#datepart-boundaries) returns the number of _boundaries_ crossed, e.g. the number of days from `2000-01-01 00:15:00` to `2000-01-01 23:45:00` is `0`, but from `2000-01-01 23:59:30` to `2000-01-02 00:00:42` is `1`. In order to get results consistent with the Access code you may need to use a smaller _datepart_, e.g. `second` rather than `day`, with a corresponding adjustment in the arithmetic, e.g. dividing by `86400`. Note that the return type is `int` which limits the range.

Comment: @Cato my point doesn't change. `2019-01-21 / 2` makes no sense. Dates aren't numbers (and h nce you by when people treat them as numbers they have problems).

Comment: @larnu date1 - date2 could mean something though, in .net it is a timespan, but the concept seems to be missing from SQL

Comment: @Cato actually it was removed (wasn't included) with `datetime2` and the other new data types; `datetime` still supports it (but again that doesn't mean it makes sense).

Comment: I agree with @Lamu on context.  The way I'm seeing this scenario, the request is to get a difference between dates and then divide by 100.  So... if there is a difference of 2 days then the results is .02?  What does .02 mean?  I don't see how it translates to something meaningful.  That being said, MS access does allow for the subtraction of two dates as the OP presented.  Dividing by 100 is the curiosity.  To that end, I don't believe the chosen answer produces the same result as MS Access because it is working as Int. I get a zero when I try it instead of a decimal value.

Comment: @level3looper - it could be part of some larger calculation, for example simple daily interest payments - if it was 1 percent per day interest for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if I am right you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, [Promise Date], [Date Recieved])/100;
```

If right you can get more details [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Actually, I think you should reverse the two date parameters

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis It might be

Comment: This did the Job. I was considering doing this initially but thought i would get the same issue when dividing by 100. Thanks @SurajKumar

Comment: Since `DateDiff` counts boundary crossings (as noted in my comment on the question) the value is likely somewhat different from that returned in Access. The TSQL code here will return the result of integer division, unlike the Access expression, unless the constant is changed (`100.0`) or a `cast` (or `convert`) is added.

Answer (score 4):

since dates in access are effectively stored as DOUBLE, I would recommend converting to the SQL float type to handle any part days

```
 (cast([Promise Date] as float) - cast([Date Recieved] as float))/100
```

check out the following example, the different ideas here give quite different answers

```
declare @x as datetime = '19960420 15:05:48';
declare @y as datetime = '19960423 18:09:23';

select (CAST(@y as float) -  CAST(@x as float)) / 100

select (CAST(@y as int) -  CAST(@x as int)) / 100

select datediff(day,@x,@y) / 100

select cast(datediff(day,@x,@y) as float) / 100
```

Access should treat the dates as floats, with the fractional part representing time, and the integer part representing days

Comment: This is the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @pd Date = '2019-01-15'
Declare @dr Date = '2019-01-12'

Select Cast(DATEDIFF(d,@dr,@pd) As Float) /100
```

Result

```
0.03
```

UPDATE: As per Cato's comment to allow for DateTime

```
Declare @pd DateTime = '2001-01-01 19:00:00'
Declare @dr DateTime = '2001-01-05 13:00:00'

Select (Cast(DATEDIFF(hh,@dr,@pd) As Float)/24) / 100
```

Result:

```
-0.0375
```

Comment: that works if his access datetime always contain whole dates, but not if they contain time components, for example 2001-01-01 19:00:00  until 2001-01-05 13:00:00  for example